# Проблема со стартом nginx Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, консоль, passenger

Устанавливаю связку nginx+passenger на VPS с Ubuntu 19.10 по [инструкции](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ubuntu-18-04-ru), но перейдя к 3 шагу что-то пошло не так, прилагаю выводы:

```
$ lsb_release -a
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
  Description:  Ubuntu 19.10
  Release:  19.10
  Codename: eoan

$ sudo ufw app list
  Available applications:
  Nginx Full
  Nginx HTTP
  Nginx HTTPS
  OpenSSH

$ sudo ufw status
  Status: active

  To                         Action      From
  --                         ------      ----
  OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
  Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
  OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
  Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)  



# Вывод с ошибкой
$ systemctl status nginx
    * nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-11-26 22:21:28 MSK; 13min ago
         Docs: man:nginx(8)
      Process: 3514 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 $ sudo service nginx restart
    Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
    See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Устанавливал всё тоже самое на Ubuntu 18.04 и никаких ошибок не было. Буду очень благодарен, если вы поможете мне решить вышеуказанную проблему. Спасибо

Comment: Читайте journalctl -u nginx и /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: что `sudo nginx -t` пишет?

Comment: @RTK,

`$ sudo nginx -t 

nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-passenger.conf" failed (2: No 
such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:4
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: Ну вот и ответ, нет такого файла.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В общем, погуглил я хорошенько, в [обсуждениях](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2104#issuecomment-516026126) гитхаба сказано, что для 19 убунты еще нет релиза, так что я поставил 18 убунту и всё заработало